Azure Function App Listen to Event Hub using Managed Identity
I am trying to create a function app on Azure with an Event Hub trigger using a managed identity. I seem to have created everything so that all the references resolve, but when I send a message to the event hub, the function app is not getting triggered (or at least, I'm not seeing the log entry it should be producing).
Trying to follow the documentation here.
Provisioning using Terraform:
main.tf

variable "resource_group_name" {}
variable "location" { default = null }

variable "function_app_name" {}
variable "event_hub_name" {}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "sp" {
  name                = "fnappserviceplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "hub" {
  name                = var.event_hub_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  capacity            = 1
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub" "hub" {
  name                = "myEventHub"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  partition_count     = 2
  message_retention   = 1
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "fnapp" {
  name                     = "safnapp"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "fnapp" {
  name                = var.function_app_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.sp.id

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.fnapp.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.fnapp.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    # tried this but it doesn't recognize the connection, so I went with the connection string instead
    # "EVENTHUB__fullyQualifiedNamespace" = "${azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.name}.servicebus.windows.net"

    "EVENTHUB"                = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.default_primary_connection_string
    "EVENTHUB_CONSUMER_GROUP" = azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group.fnapp.name
  }

  site_config {
    always_on = true

    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.11"
    }
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group" "fnapp" {
  name                = "${var.function_app_name}ConsumerGroup"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.hub.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

And then the main function:
function_app.py
import logging
import os

import azure.functions as func


app = func.FunctionApp()


@app.function_name(name="mylistener")
@app.event_hub_message_trigger(arg_name="hub",
                               event_hub_name="myEventHub",
                               connection="EVENTHUB",
                               consumer_group=os.getenv("EVENTHUB_CONSUMER_GROUP", "$Default"))
def myeventlistener(hub: func.EventHubEvent):
    event_body = hub.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    logging.info(f'Python EventHub trigger processed an event: {event_body}')

After provisioning, I add the "Azure Event Hubs Data Receiver" role to this function app on the resource group. (And "Azure Event Hubs Data Owner" to myself for my own interactions with the event hub.)
I then deploy the code using func azure functionapp publish MyFunctionAppName, and monitor using func azure functionapp logstream MyFunctionAppName. (This logstream is where I expect to see the logging.info() output. Or at least some system logs indicating the function has been triggered. Is this correct?)
When inspecting the connection on the Azure portal (mylistener function > Integration > Triggers > Azure Event Hub) all the parameters appear correct and the Connection seems to be recognized – it's not giving me "No connection found" or anything, it's using the named connection I set in the app settings.
After waiting for all the setup/launching/initializing to settle down, I then publish a (plaintext) message to the event hub (not the namespace). I have tried sending specifically to each partition. I expect the log message to appear but it does not. I see no indication that the function is getting triggered.
UPDATE
ChatGPT suggested that this doesn't use managed identities if I feed it a connection string, and instead I should set EVENTHUB = azurerm_eventhub.hub.name in order to use managed identities. It was double-minded on whether the argument in Python should be connection="EVENTHUB" or connection="EVENTHUB__fullyQualifiedNamespace". I tried both (while uncommenting the one line in the tf app_settings), and with both, it gives me "No existing connections available" when I check the trigger's connection on the portal. I also get the message "Azure.Messaging.EventHubs: The connection string could not be parsed; either it was malformed or contains no well-known tokens."

Did you assign the Azure Event Hubs Data Receiver role to functionapp's managed identity?

Yes. I assigned it at the resource group, and checked the event hub's IAM, it is getting inherited as expected.

Check if below solution helps.

Follow below steps to establish connection between Azure function app and Event Hub using managed identity.

Create an EventHub and Event Hub Trigger in Azure function App.
Enable Managed Identity in Azure function App. I have enabled System Managed Identity.
Navigate to Event Hub=>Access Role(IAM)=>Add Role Assignment, assign Azure EventHub Data Owner and Azure Event Hub Data Receiver to Function App's Managed Identity.




Add the application setting <CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__fullyQualifiedNamespace=<eventhub_name>.servicebus.windows.net under Functionapp=>settings=>Environment Variables=>App Settings:

CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX should be the connection value you have used in the function code.


Update EventHub name in the function code.

Code Snippet:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.event_hub_message_trigger(arg_name="azeventhub", event_hub_name="<eventhub_name>",
                               connection="rkspace_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB") 
def eventhub_trigger1(azeventhub: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                azeventhub.get_body().decode('utf-8'))


Send the events:



Able to trigger the function:

You can check the function logs under Function=>Invocation Logs. select the particular log to see the detailed output/invocation.


This is the solution I arrived at with ChatGPT but it didn't appear to be working. Turns out it is in fact triggering, it's just not putting the log output where I would have expected to find it. (It's also not recognizing the connection in the Integration blade.) Where can I find the full logs? As noted in the OP, I checked the logstream and it doesn't show up there. I would hate to think that Application Insights is the ONLY mechanism available to find out such basic information as whether the function app was even invoked.

Did you try with any other plans?

Do you mean the service plan? No. To clarify, this does work, as does the OP. I just didn't see it working because I was looking in the wrong place for the logs apparently.

This answer is mostly a restatement of the OP. I'd prefer the answer focuses on what I was missing -- namely, the specific naming convention for the connection argument (it's there but a bit buried) and the fact that I was looking for the logs in the wrong place (again, it's there but not addressed specifically). If Pravallika revises it to focus on the specific problem from the OP, I'll be happy to accept it.

Please check the updated answer @user2100826.

Better, but I think you're missing what I'm asking for. The key details are still buried among a wall of other information -- information which is already a restatement of the OP. As per the meta link that @Naveen Sharma helpfully shared, I'm holding out for a short time for a more relevant/focused answer before I accept this one.

Credit to @Pravallika KV's answer for containing the information I needed. TL/DR version follows.
The update to the OP was the correct configuration. I was looking in the wrong place for logs so it did not appear to be working. Also, with this configuration, the "Integration" tab on the Function shows "No existing connections available" under the Event Hub trigger, implying there is no connection, even though it is in fact connecting and triggering properly. (Bug?)
The following modification to the OP Terraform setup works:
main.tf
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "fnapp" {
  # ...

  app_settings = {
    "EVENTHUB__fullyQualifiedNamespace" = "${azurerm_eventhub_namespace.hub.name}.servicebus.windows.net"
    "EVENTHUB_CONSUMER_GROUP"           = azurerm_eventhub_consumer_group.fnapp.name
  }

  # ...
}

function_app.py in OP may be used as is. connection should be the portion of the environment variable before the __fullyQualifiedNamespace. So, for example, with an environment variable called EVENTHUB__fullyQualifiedNamespace, you want connection="EVENTHUB". Be sure not to also include an environment variable called EVENTHUB.
I have not found a way to view the logs from the log stream, even by forcing to stdout. However, the logs are accessible using the (small charge paid service) Application Insights, which must be enabled in order to view them. This can be done using the web portal or through Terraform. Once enabled, invocations are recorded under the "Invocations" tab of the Function. Log entries will appear individually when selecting a specific run.
